# Simple Port Scanner in Python - Error: an integer is required

Tags: python, port

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket

ip = input('Enter the IP address: ')
port = input('Enter the Port: ')

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

if s.connect_ex((ip,port)):
        print ('Port', port, 'is closed')
else:
        print ('Port', port, 'is open')
```

As you can see, it is a very simply port scanner that I have attempted to run (currently learning some Penetration Testing).

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python.py", line 9, in <module>
    if s.connect_ex((ip,port)):
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I assume that I need to set line 9 as an integer - how do I do this?

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Thank you for posting a full error traceback. What do you think the error means?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: @quamrana I believe it means that I need to set line 9 as an integer. However, I don't know how to do this is such context.

Comment: As you can see from the answers, its actually only complaining about the `port` parameter of the `connect_ex` method. That method requires an integer as the second parameter, but the more you learn about python and its libraries the easier it will become to diagnose these things.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you for clarifying this - I've solved that issue now (time to deal with the next). Not sure if your first comment was being sarcastic. I.e. It's not that acceptable to post full error tracebacks. Sorry if it came accross as If I didn't want to put any effort in myself.

Comment: Not at all sarcastic. Its a failing of many posters to post incomplete information. Your post was complete with code **and** a traceback. Good question.

Comment: @quamrana Oh, good. :) Thanks for the help, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here: `port = input('Enter the Port: ')` you read user input which is a `str` and you pass it as port number (which should be as you've probably already guessed an `int`). You traceback is telling you exactly the same thing. You need to convert the port to integer with calling `int(port)`

Answer (score 0):

```
port = int(input('Enter the Port: '))
```

Comment: You can also use: `if not port.isdigit(): print("eroor try again")`

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns a string, which you need to convert into an integer. Converting strings to *valid* integers can be a rather complex task. For a first approach change

```
port = input('Enter the Port: ')
```

into

```
port = input('Enter the Port: ')
try:
    port = int(port)
except ValueError as err:
    print('Invalid input. Please try again.')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much appreciated.